# Como fazer um for dentro de um html += do Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Olá pessoal estou com um problema e queria uma ajuda.
Como eu posso fazer um `for` dentro de `html +=` do ajax?

JS:

```
$('.requerAjax').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var mes = $(this).attr('rel');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/admin/galeria/fotos-ajax",
        data: "mes="+ mes,
        datatype: 'json',
        beforeSend: function(){
        },
        success: function(result){
            var i = 0;
            var result = result[i];
            // console.log(result);            

            var html = "";

            html += "<div id="+ result.mes + result.ano +" class='modal fade' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>";
            html += "<div class='modal-dialog'>";                
            html += "<div class='modal-content'>";
            html += "<div class='modal-header'>";
            html += "<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>×</button>";
            html += "<h4 class='modal-title'>"+ result.mes +"/"+ result.ano +"</h4>";
            html += "</div>";
            html += "<div class='modal-body'>";
            html += "<div class='gallery'>"; 
            // for ( $i < result.length; $i++) {

                   html += "<img src="+ result.imagem +" alt=''>";

            // }                     
            html += "</div>";
            html += "</div>";
            html += "<div class='modal-footer'>";
            html += "<button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>Fechar</button>";
            html += "</div>";
            html += "</div>";
            html += "</div>";
            html += "</div>"

            $( ".areaModal" ).html(html);
        }
    });
```

Eu tenho um modal que dentro dele vai vir varias fotos.
Eu quero colocar o For dentro do modal, aqui dentro:

```
 html += "<div class='gallery'>"; 
     // for ( $i < result.length; $i++) {                
     html += "<img src="+ result.imagem +" alt=''>";                
     // }                     
 html += "</div>";
```

Comment: Junta por favor à pergunta o JSON que estás a receber (podes fazer `console.log(JSON.stringify(result));` logo no inicio dessa função).

Comment: Ele me retorna `{"mes":"Dezembro","ano":"2014","imagem":"/assets/galeria/fotos/2014_Dezembro_1_1_1.jpg"}`

Comment: Ok, mas é só um objeto? ou uma array de objetos? estás a fazer esse `console.log` antes ou depois de `var result = result[i];`? e porque tens isso assim? estás a limitar os resultados ao primeiro da array... (estou a fazer perguntas para perceber melhor o problema e poder ajudar melhor)

Comment: É só um Objeto, este console.log `console.log(JSON.stringify(result));` esta logo abaixo do `var result = result[i];`. Este `var result = result[i];` para eu poder pegar os outro resultados que esta vindo tipo  o `html += "<h4 class='modal-title'>"+ result.mes +"/"+ result.ano +"</h4>";`.

Comment: Mas então o `result` original (argumento da função) é uma array. Não estarão as outras imagens aí? pois no JSON que colocaste a chave `imagem` só tem um `src` e tu queres fazer um loop com quais imagens?

Comment: Si eu tiro o `var i = 0;  var result = result[i];` e deixo o `console.log(JSON.stringify(result));` ele me retornar as 3 imagens `[{"mes":"Dezembro","ano":"2014","imagem":"/assets/galeria/fotos/2014_Dezembro_1_1_1.jpg"},{"mes":"Dezembro","ano":"2014","imagem":"/assets/galeria/fotos/2014_Dezembro_1_1_2.jpg"},{"mes":"Dezembro","ano":"2014","imagem":"/assets/galeria/fotos/2014_Dezembro_1_1_3.jpg"},{"mes":"Dezembro","ano":"2014","imagem":"/assets/galeria/fotos/2014_Dezembro_1_1_4.jpg"}]`

Comment: Ok e são essas as imagens que queres ter no `for` e no modal?

Comment: Sim, mas agora ele não esta montando o modal, acho que porque estou chamando em 2 lugares `+ result.mes +"/"+ result.ano +` si eu colocar o `console.log(JSON.stringify(result.imagem));` ele me retonar `undefined`, mas si eu vou em **Network** em **Preview** ele me retornar os 3 imagens.

Comment: No HTML com classe `'.requerAjax'` está a informação do mês certo? tem a informação do ano algures também no HTML?

Comment: Olha tenho de ir. Acho que o que precisas é isto: http://jsfiddle.net/h5z3d86d/  - gostava de saber mais dados para te dar a melhor resposta, mas talvez amanhã. Repara que retirei esse `var i = 0;  var result = result[i];` e dei o ano como 2014. O ideal era isso também estar no HTML. Na(s) proxima(s) perguntas aqui coloca mais dados que vais ter respostas mais acertadas. Bom ano!

Comment: Sim tem que parecer, este é a imagem: http://tinypic.com/r/2zhfiie/8

Comment: Um `underscore.js` nesse caso cairia muito bem!

Answer (score 1):

O for loop no JavaScript deve ser:

```
for (var i = 0, i < result.length; i++){
```

Tu estás a fazer `for ( $i < result.length; $i++) {` que é incorreto pois o $i não está defenido.

Por norma não se usa `$` em variáveis numéricas no JavaScript. Até funcionava mas terias de fazer `for (var $i = 0, etc` pelo menos.

Outro problema é que deves usar `result.imagem[i]` dentro do loop, e não `result.imagem`. Isto partindo do principio que esse `result.imagem` é uma array.

Assim o loop deveria ser:

```
for (var i = 0, i < result.length; i++){
    html += "<img src="+ result[i].imagem +" alt=''>";
}
```

Uma sugestão para o código completo seria:

```
$('.requerAjax').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var mes = $(this).attr('rel');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/admin/galeria/fotos-ajax",
        data: "mes=" + mes,
        datatype: 'json',
        beforeSend: function () {},
        success: function (result) {
            var ano = 2014; // seria interessante ter isto a vir também do HTML!
            // console.log(result);            
            var html = "";
            html += "<div id=" + mes + ano + " class='modal fade' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>";
            html += "<div class='modal-dialog'>";
            html += "<div class='modal-content'>";
            html += "<div class='modal-header'>";
            html += "<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>×</button>";
            html += "<h4 class='modal-title'>" + mes + "/" + ano + "</h4>";
            html += "</div>";
            html += "<div class='modal-body'>";
            html += "<div class='gallery'>";
            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                html += "<img src=" + result[i].imagem + " alt=''>";
            }
            html += "</div>";
            html += "</div>";
            html += "<div class='modal-footer'>";
            html += "<button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>Fechar</button>";
            html += "</div>";
            html += "</div>";
            html += "</div>";
            html += "</div>"
            $(".areaModal").html(html);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Sergio vlw por responder!
Sim eu já tinha feito sem o $, e mesmo sem o $ quando eu clico no botão ele não faz nada. 
html += "<div class='gallery'>"; 
  for ( i < result.length; i++) {                
    html += "<img src="+ result.imagem +" alt=''>";                
  }                     
html += "</div>";

Comment: Não esta funcionando! Sem o $.

Comment: coloquei como você falou, mas agora ele esta fazendo um loop em cada letra do cominho da imagem. Mas só me retornou uma só. 
`for (var i = 0; i < result.imagem.length; i++){                
    html += "<img src="+ result.imagem[i] +" alt=''>";                
} `
**ASSIM:** `<div class="gallery"><img src="/" alt=""><img src="a" alt=""><img src="s" alt=""><img src="s" alt=""><img src="e" alt=""><img src="t" alt=""><img src="s" alt=""><img src="/" alt=""><img src="e" alt=""><img src="m" alt=""><img src="p" alt=""><img src="r" alt=""><img src="e" alt=""><img src="e" alt="">`

Comment: @MichaelFernandes ok. Coloca por favor o JSON que recebes na pergunta que assim a resposta vai ser correta.

Comment: @MichaelFernandes você retirou a linha `var result = result[i];` logo no início do script? Isto iria quebrar com o script que o @Sergio colocou.